# Grouped notifications fire the same pending intent

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am grouping multiple notifications into one group, each notification has a different pending intent.
When any of the notifications in the group is clicked the same pending intent is fired (the one added to the last added notification).
What I was expecting is each notification should fire its own intent.

Summary notification:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder groupSummaryBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setContentTitle("title")
                    .setContentText("message")
                    .setGroupSummary(true)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setGroup(GROUP_ID)
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message));
```

Group notofications:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), CHANNEL_ID);
    notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(title);
    notificationBuilder.setContentText(message);
    notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    notificationBuilder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX);
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    notificationBuilder.setGroup(GROUP_ID);
    notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
```

What am I missing here?